# Is it a bad idea to use leftover cali bamboo flooring for a garden bed?

Tags: raised-beds

It's this stuff: https://www.calibamboo.com/product-mocha-fossilized-eucalyptus-flooring-7008002401.html

I figure it's low VOC, will look decent, and I've already got it, so why not? Or am I underestimating the chemical seepage into plants? Maybe also missing how quick this stuff will rot?

Answer (score 2):

As a rule, I would not use anything treated in the garden. I woudl suggest that unlike, within a home, the coatings and chemicals will dislodge from most treated items because of

- cycles of heating and cooling
- cycles of dryness and drenching
- UV
- scratching from pets and birds
- attempted ingestion by bugs and worms